# java socket programming : message delivery order

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am new to any kind of network programming. Please could you answer the following.

I am using Java.

Scenario

Thread 1:

```
Socket s = new Socket("remote machine", portNum);
//get the outputstream and write **"Message 1"**, close it.
```

Thread 2:

```
Socket s = new Socket("remote machine", portNum);    
//get the outputstream and write **"Message 2"**, close it.
```

It is certain that the Thread 1 opens socket and sends the message to remote machine before the Thread 2 does in real time.

Is it guaranteed that the "Remote machine" reads them in the same order, i.e. reads Message 1, and then Message 2

**Note**: The order is guaranteed because the Thread 1, after sending the Message 1, sends an approval to Thread 2 to proceed.

Comment: Well, I'm not pretty sure, but it looks like two different TCP connections to the same machine. As far as packets could go in not so predictable way (say using different routes), the message2 has pretty good change to be first.

Comment: Since there is no guarantee that the network didn't drop message1 the answer is no. There is no guaranteed that the "Remote machine" reads them in the same order.

Comment: @ahenderson, thanks for the reply. I am not very much aware of underlying mechanism, however, I think the default is TCP and it doesn't drop messages, right?

Comment: TCP can drop packets (parts of the message), which will be resent. This means the arrival of the full message will be delayed.

Comment: if you use 2 different sockets there are no guarantees at all. and while TCP delivers all messages, it retransmits them if need arises (i.e. a message had been dropped/not delivered). There are no intrinsic benefit of using 2 sockets in general.

Comment: thanks for the replies, the reason for using two client sockets is that the Thread 1 and Thread 2 are running on different machines..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to imagine the network as something

a) asynchronous
b) unreliable
c) uncontrollable

so, when you send something, things will happen in parallel under uncontrollable circumstances. when you send something to a remote machine it isn't even guaranteed, that the data (initial and data - see TCP) is transmitted via the same path.

TCP manages sequential transmissions for a single connection quite well, but not for two. if you use/need two to the same server/port, you normally do that because you want them to be independent. You're programming in Java, try to sync/dispatch on a single tcp-socket-connection for delivery order guarantees and use multiple to run things in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.. it explains the uncertainty... btw, did you mean that if I use same "Socket" object for multiple threads, the order of whole-message-delivery is guaranteed?

Comment: when you do a synchronized(socket){..} yes. else things may(!) mix. better use something like message(id)->queue->local.senderthread ... receiverthread(remote)->worker->reply(id)->queue->remote.senderthread ... local.receiverthread->queue->reply(id)  and care that the message(id) gets the right reply(id)

Comment: ... means one socket (or multiple, if you can do things in parallel)

Comment: and if you need something now and ready, check for JMS pattern and implementations, like apache activemq